# HTTP post, get and variables

Tags: http, post, get

How can I monitor exactly what information my browser sends with GET and/or POST methods to a web page? I mean not only the name of the parameters, but also the values.

```
F.eks.: http://somesite.com/?user=name&password=pass
```

When I log on to a web site with a form for username and password, I would like to know the URL the form post/get action sends to, and the names of the variables (above: user, password) as well as the values (above: name, pass).

How is this easiest accomplished? With a package sniffer like WireShark? With a local proxy server?

All advice, as well as specific appliactions and a quick intro on how to get the exact information, is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the easiest way is with developer tools.

F12 in Chrome and IE and Firebug in Firefox.

If you're wanting something a little more in depth, try [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Comment: Thanks. Those seem to be the easiest solutions. I'm no closer to solving my actual problem, but I got my answer :)